# How to make JQuery css to be drawn without delay?

Tags: jquery, css, function, twitter-bootstrap, delayed-job

I'm facing a wired issue. Using bootstrap, I coded some layouts similar to this:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4" id="block1">Some short text</div>
    <div class="span4" id="block2">Some LONG text<br/>displayed on<br/>multiple lines</div>
    <div class="span4" id="block3">Some short text</div>
</div>
```

My custom CSS adds some decoration and each `.span*` has its frontiers visible (border, shadow, etc.). As a result, `#block2` is taller than `#block1` and `#block3`. I coded a function `autoAlign()` that parses all `.span*` in each `.row-fluid` and adjusts their height using `$(this).css('height', value)` so each `.span*` in each `.row-fluid` has the same height. Up to here, everything works fine.

In my project, I have something like this:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span8" id="left">Some VERY LONG text<br />...<br />...</div>
    <div class="span4" id="right">
        <div class="row-fluid">
             <div class="span12">Some fields</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
             <div class="span12" id="graph"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here `#left` is taller than `#right` and, **in a function**, I call `autoAlign()` to make `#right` the same height as `#left` and, then, to draw a chart in `#graph` with jqplot. I need to change the height of `#graph` prior to draw a chart with *jqplot* in order the chart to use as much height as possible.

My problem is the adjustments made with `autoAlign()` are not taken into account immediately by the browser (here Chrome 27), even if I can see `style="height: NNNpx"` has been added to each `.span*` element. As a result, if I try to access the height of `#right` with either `$('#right').height()` or `$('#right').css('height')` I get the current height (i.e. without `style="height: NNNpx"` taken into account) and thus, I'm not able to compute the required size for `#graph` in order this element to feet all the remaining space in `#right`. The CSS changes are only applied on screen when exiting the function

So, my question is the following: is there a way to force the browser to repaint/apply the recent CSS changes?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you give some indication of the layout (that is, the CSS)? It sounds to me like you could set the main container to display: table and the spans to display: table-cell, though your second example makes things look more complex ... and I'm assuming things sit side by side here? Because it takes JS time to load, you won't get instant styles via JS. You are better off using CSS in the first place, and display: table is good for getting equal heights.

Comment: @ralph.m: the CSS is managed via bootstrap library. I do not plan to override its behavior implementations in order to be able to update bootstrap without introducing incompatibilities.

Comment: Ah, the misery of frameworks! I don't know why people lumber themselves with these things. :( But I don't see why you can't add in a class or two and provide unique styling just for those elements. Couldn't you have a separate style sheet for things like this?